# empty() not working when mysql is fetching array

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure why this isnt working. I'm assuming it's because i am fetching an array but not sure why that would stop it.

Heres the code anyhow;

```
<?php  

include ("../database.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE artisturl='$artistname'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if (empty($row['gigname'])){echo  '<p2>'.$row['artistname']. 'has not posted any gigs     yet. Check back later.</p2>';}
else {
echo     $row['gigname'].$row['venue'].$row['lineup'].$row['date'].$row['time'].$row['price'].$row['    purchase'].'<br><br>';}}?>
```

Comment: Be more specific, what isn't working? What outcome would you expect and what outcome actually occurs?

Comment: Try `var_dump($row['gigname']);` and make absolutely sure that the contents of that variable is empty ([according to documentaion](http://php.net/empty))

Comment: You aren't even verfying if the query was successful or not, you should do that before proceeding with `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say that, kind of the most important bit. The echo for the empty isn't returning so im assuming the empty() isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure why this isnt working

You've not stated what your criteria for 'working' are.

Your code doen't make any sense. empty() is not the right function to use here - indeed there is no function which will work here because if there are no matching records then the body of the loop will never execute.

There are lots of ways to deal with the scenario. Here's a simple one:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo ....
   }
} else {
   echo  '<p2>'.$row['artistname']. 'has not posted any gigs...'
}
```

Comment: Please read the comments above. Thanks for the answer though and ill test this out

Answer (score 1):

Empty has unexpected results with strings, i'd suggest you read [this](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/09/careful-with-php-empty.html) article.

For example :

```
    $mystring = '0';
if (empty($mystring)) {
    // this code will run
    // what if this was code to take action when $mystring is undefined?
}
```

So make sure gigname is not 0.

Consider using `is_null($row['gigname']))`